# how do you clear memory usage?

Tags: python, tensorflow

i have this simplified python script for `token_backup` has a  class script with a couple methods

`forecast_token` : fetches info about the token to train on an returns a data frame with pandas

`make_data` : prepares data for training and trains on it in the same method

`predict_token` : predicts next token and outputs info as graph

every thing works fine works fine with token_backup but during execution i noticed that every time i loop in `while True` my RAM usage goes up about 100MB until it fills up the whole RAM and then crash the IDE

is there any way to clear the old 100MB  before or clear the memory usage or is there any method to keep the script running with out eating all of my RAM

```
from tokens_backup import *

import random 

tokens = ['67878' ,'21353' ,'34553']


def train_token(token , x):
    for i in range (x):
        obj_x = fetch_token(token)
        obj_x.forecast_token()
        obj_x.make_data()
        c_token, t_token = obj_x.predict_token()

    return c_token , t_token


while True:
    time.sleep(30)
    train_token(token=random.choice(tokens), x=4)
```

Comment: What is `tokens_backup`? Is it using some modeling package?

Comment: i am using tensor flow to train a model on some numbers

Comment: I don't know what your functions do, but it they add data to a model that keeps growing you may be stuck.